# Java String to Json & vice versa

Tags: java, regex, json, string, parsing

I want to covert a string based protocol to  Json, Performance is key

The  String based protocol is something like

```
<START>A12B13C14D15<END>
```

and json is

```
{'A':12,'B':13,'C':14,'D':15}
```

I can regex parse the string, create a map & serialized to a Json, but it seeems lot of work as I need to convert a stream in realtime. 
Would it be more efficient if I just do string manipulation to get the Json output? How can I do the conversion efficiently?

Comment: Well, I believe there's no such Library as *Convert String to JSON with Alphabet as Property and int as Value* so I *guess* you would have to do it like you've said: *parse the string, create a map & serialized to a Json* (this you can use GSON if you want)

Comment: FSM to the rescue (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Comment: Um, all joking aside, use an efficient JSON library like Jackson or GSON to do encoding and/or decoding. Chances are it will be faster than hand-written code (unless spending non-trivial amount of time) -- you do NOT need to create a `Map`, just use streaming interfaces (`JsonGenerator`). And with generation speeds in excess of 200MB/sec, really, this will not be your bottleneck (network or I/O will be)

Comment: If that's as complex as it gets, you do not, of course, need to create a Map and then serialize the Map to JSON, but you can instead just generate the JSON with simple string concatenation.  But if it's more complex, using Maps and Arrays is not particularly inefficient and is much easier to keep straight.

Comment: (And of course note that JSON object key values should be enclosed in *double quotes* (`"`).)

Comment: I generally recommend against using String concatenation for any XML or JSON generation, since escaping and other aspects will generally cause problems. Not a problem here, with this data, but things tend to grow. But this problem can definitely be solved in multiple ways, and I doubt performance will be a problem with any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSON serialization performance is likely not a problem. Don't optimize it prematurely.** If you roll your own JSON serializer, you need to put some effort into e.g. getting the escapes right. If the performance does become a problem, take a look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), which is fairly fast.

Java seems to do regex quite fast, so you might be fine with it but beware that it is quite possible to accidentally build a regex that with some inputs starts backtracking heavily and takes several minutes to evaluate. You could use native String methods to parse the string.

If performance is really a concern, do timing tests on different approaches, select right tools, see what takes time and optimize accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to go about it, on JSON side. Instead of `Map`, which is not needed, POJO is often most convenient. Following uses Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) library:

```
final static ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper(); // remember to reuse for good perf

public class ABCD {
  public int A, B, C, D;
}

// if you have output stream handy:
ABCD value = new ABCD(...);
OutputStream out = ...;
MAPPER.writeValue(out, value);
// or if not
byte[] raw = MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(value);
```

or, if you want to eliminate even more of overhead (which, really, is unlikely to matter here):

`JsonGenerator jgen = MAPPER.getFactory().createGenerator(out);
jgen.writeStartObject();
jgen.writeNumberField("A", valueA);
jgen.writeNumberField("B", valueB);
jgen.writeNumberField("C", valueC);
jgen.writeNumberField("D", valueD);
jgen.writeEndObject();
jgen.close();`

and that gets to quite to close to optimal performance you'd get with hand-written code.

Comment: Using a POJO and a mapper is probably less efficient than using a Map.

Comment: @HotLicks I doubt that. POJOs are more efficient data structures (Maps require key storage, indirect lookup by key; POJOs have direct index offsets). But it depends on JSON lib implementation -- all I can say is that with Jackson, POJOs will be faster in general.

Comment: @HotLicks Let's see. I wrote this -- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2007/02/entry_32.html -- 7 years ago; and this -- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/04/entry_396.html -- bit later. So yes, I do know what I am talking about. Also, having written one JSON library, 2 XML libraries (Woodstox, Aalto), as well as worked on performance benchmarks (https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers), I know quite a bit about performance in this domain.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I used this library to handle with json in a web application.

Don't remember where to find. May this helps:

http://www.findjar.com/class/org/json/JSONArray.html